# TableView unexpectedly resizing bounds

Tags: swift, uitableview, bounds

I have two view controllers, one of which is a `UICollectionViewController`, and the other is a `UITableViewController`. When I run the app and check the debug view hierarchy, the Collection View has a frame with origin (0,0), as expected, but the Table View's origin is (0,-44).

**What I think the problem is:**
I assume this is because of autoresizing, because printing the tableView's bounds in `viewDidLoad()` shows that the tableView has a bounds with origin (0,0), but printing the tableView's bounds in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` shows the origin being (0,-44).

**Why this is a problem:** I add a `UIView` as a subview of `view`, and attempt to resize the tableView to end at a certain constant height above the bottom of the screen, with the `UIView` taking up the remaining space at the bottom of the screen. This works fine with in the `UICollectionViewController`, where the bounds has origin (0,0), but since the tableView's bounds' origin has a negative y-value, the UIView is cut off at the bottom of the screen.

**What I've tried:** I set the tableView's bounds' origin to `CGPoint.zero` in `viewDidLoad()`, but that did not work, because it is resized after `viewDidLoad()`. I  set the tableView's bounds' origin to `CGPoint.zero`, and the size to a value that would leave room for the `UIView` at the bottom (the tableView's size - the UIView's size) in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, and that resized the tableView properly, but caused the `UIView` to disappear for some reason. Only adjusting the tableView's origin caused the `UIView` to appear properly, but the tableView overlapped with the `UIView`, which I don't want.
Also, since the view lays out subviews very often (e.g., when scrolling the tableView), the app runs the code in `viewDIdLayoutSubviews()` far too often, causing lag.

Also, I would like if someone could explain why the tableView's bounds are resized to a non-`CGPoint.zero` value, while the collectionView remains at `CGPoint.zero`

**Edit 1:**

Screenshots were requested in the comments, so here is a screenshot of the `UITableViewController` and the correct `UICollectionViewController`, respectively (I was unable to resize the images properly, so hopefully this is good enough):

[image]
[image]

Here are links to the full sized images for the
[UITableViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uycV2.png) and [UICollectionViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbQQa.png).

**Edit 2:**

I also printed the `view` and `tableView`'s constraints, and neither of them have any constraints.

Comment: Can you show screenshots?

Comment: 44 is the height of the iOS navigation bar. It must be something related to the presence of a navigation bar in one of the screens and the tableview trying to automatically adjust its position based on it.

Comment: If you are using AutoLayout, you could have one view setup where the top constraint is to the superview.top and the other is to the safe area.top; which would exhibit the behaviour you are describing. Show us your constraints and we can see if that is the issue.

Comment: @canister_exister I just edited the question to include screenshots.

Comment: @GabrielBeltrameSilva How come the CollectionViewController does not have problem with its bounds then? I have set `isNavigationBarHidden` to true for both Controllers, but this problem is only occurring for the tableView.

Comment: @FJdeBrienne I have not added any constraints to any of my views. Whatever AutoResizing that is occurring, its happening by default. I don't mind preventing the default AutoResizing from happening, but I'm afraid that can cause problems down the road.

Comment: @FJdeBrienne I printed the `view` and `tableView`'s constraints, and both have none.

Comment: @RPatel99 bounds is not what you're looking for. You want to look at a view's `frame` property to see how it is placed inside its `superview`. So `view.frame.origin` should be CGPoint.zero for a view at the origin. Can you look at the view frames and report back? Thanks.

Comment: @RPatel99 also, is there any reason you're not using Auto Layout? I know it's unrelated but that problem would be solved in an instant using Auto Layout, I think.

Comment: @RPatel99 also, if you do want to play with it in code, set the `frame`, not the `bounds`, as I mentioned previously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186430/discussion-between-rpatel99-and-fj-de-brienne).